# Selenium - need position relative to another object on the page?

Tags: c#, selenium

In my problem, I have a checkbox that is dynamically named (I have thanked my Developers for that already) so I can't find the object based on ID.  I have used QTP in the past and was able to select an object based on the position of it relative to other objects that were easier to identify.  In this case, there is a list of checkboxes with descriptions.  While the checkbox name changes, the text in the list next to it stays the same.

Is it possible to say something like - click the checkbox to the left of object A?

Sorry if this is a bit vague, I am new to Selenium.  Just looking for a starting point, not every element of the code needed.  Thanks!

HTML sample:

```
<div class="select-measures-table">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if=" vm.isSearchDataLoaded == true">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-include="'measureGrid.html'">
<table class="table ng-scope" ng-show="vm.measures.length > 0">
<tbody>
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-include="'measureRow.html'" ng-repeat="measure in vm.measures track by measure.ThisMeasureId | orderBy:'MeasureId'">
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-include="'measureRow.html'" ng-repeat="measure in vm.measures track by measure.ThisMeasureId | orderBy:'MeasureId'">
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-include="'measureRow.html'" ng-repeat="measure in vm.measures track by measure.ThisMeasureId | orderBy:'MeasureId'">
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-include="'measureRow.html'" ng-repeat="measure in vm.measures track by measure.ThisMeasureId | orderBy:'MeasureId'">
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-include="'measureRow.html'" ng-repeat="measure in vm.measures track by measure.ThisMeasureId | orderBy:'MeasureId'">
```

Comment: share the html source.... u can look at xpath or css selectors which allow traversing from one object to another...

Comment: added sample of the table

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your HTML code I can see that you are testing an Angular JS application which might be why Selenium is not working. In that case use [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) to write JS tests or [Protractor.Net](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net) to write C# tests.

Both are built on top of Selenium and provide constructs specifically for dealing with Angular SPAs.

Comment: I am using the IDE, but I think my problem lies in that this is a table on the page.  The IDE is not recording when I check the boxes.  Thanks though.

Comment: @JamesCraig That's surprising, I have never seen it not record something. As for the table, that's not a supposed to be a problem.

Comment: @JamesCraig I've changed my answer since I learned you were testing an Angular JS application.